# Where does the rule in the standard specify that a function with a trailing-return-type whose return type contains a placeholder type should be `auto`

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
auto* fun()->int*{}
int main(){
}
```

This [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/szrrG6) is rejected by both Clang and GCC, and they report an error, which is

> 'fun' function with trailing return type has 'auto*' as its type rather than plain 'auto'

However, I haven't found any rule that forbids this usage in the standard. The only relevant rule that I feel correspond is the following:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> > ```
> >  D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq opt
> >     ref-qualifier opt noexcept-specifier opt attribute-specifier-seq opt trailing-return-type
> > ```
>
> and the type of the contained declarator-id in the declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list T”, **T shall be the single type-specifier auto**.

However, according to [dcl.meaning#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.meaning#3), which says:

> Thus, a declaration of a particular identifier has the form
>
> > T D

> where T is of the form attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq and D is a declarator.

Hence, back to this example, `T` is auto and the declarator is `*fun()->int*`. So, `T` here is a single type-specifier auto, the declaration does not violate any rule. Why do GCC and Clang both reject the valid code? If I miss the rule that forbids this usage in the standard, what's the rule?

Comment: "*Hence, back to this example, `T` is auto and the declarator is `*fun()->int*`.*" How do you reach that conclusion? Why wouldn't `T` be `auto *` in your example?

Comment: @NicolBolas Could you find a notation `*` in the grammar tree of decl-specifier-seq?  In other words, why not you don't think `*` is a part of declarator as per [dcl.decl#nt:declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#nt:declarator)?

Comment: You need to go through dcl.meaning in order, which means [dcl.ptr] first.

Comment: It seems to me that you want the `*` to be part of the *return type* not the *function declarator*. If it was part of the *function declarator* would you not need to be declaring a *function pointer*?

Comment: @T.C. That's exactly. according to the match, `auto* fun()->int*` is first matched [dcl.ptr] where T is `auto` and the specified `D1` is `fun()->int*`. So, you mean `T D1` which has the form `auto fun()->int*` violates the rule?

Comment: It doesn't, but the type determined from `T D1` does not have the form "_derived-declarator-type-list_ T".

Comment: to be clear, you think fun is a function pointer?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I didn't say the type of `fun` is a function pointer. What's the type of `fun` is determined by the whole [dcl.decl]

Comment: @T.C. You mean `T D1` which is `auto fun()->int*`, which decomposed by [dcl.ptr], does not have "derived-declarator-type-list T"?

Comment: It's "function of () returning pointer to int". Where is `T` aka `auto` in there?

Comment: @T.C. It seems you're right, we couldn't find the `derived-declarator-type-list` based on `T`(aka auto). Giving an answer would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the grammar. This was [core issue 681](https://wg21.link/CWG681).

```
declarator:
  ptr-declarator
  noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type

ptr-declarator:
  noptr-declarator
  ptr-operator ptr-declarator

noptr-declarator:
  declarator-id attribute-specifier-seq_opt
  noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
  noptr-declarator [ constant-expression_opt ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
  ( ptr-declarator )
```

`*f () -> whatever` is not a valid *declarator*; the grammar disallows a *ptr-declarator* at that position. (It follows that it is unsurprising that the rules for interpreting *declarators* don't provide for this occasion - as discussed in the comments.)

Comment: Wonderful. It's a briefly answer. I forgot the grammar disallows such usage!

Answer (score 0):

[[dcl.fct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#2) states:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
> D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq-opt 
>   ref-qualifier-opt noexcept-specifier-opt attribute-specifier-seq-opt trailing-return-type
> ```
>
> and the type of the contained declarator-id in the declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list T”, **T shall be the single type-specifier auto.**[...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

which is where it is required to be `auto`.

Comment: As I said in my question, T denotes `decl-specifier-seq`, for the declaration `auto *fun()->int*`, it first matches [dcl.ptr] where T is `auto` and D1 is `fun()->int*`. In any case, the operator `*` is as the part of declarator.

Comment: @jackX `D1` is required to be *“derived-declarator-type-list noexcept
o
p
t
 function of parameter-type-list cv-qualifier-seq
o
p
t
 ref-qualifier
o
p
t
 returning U”,...*. `*fun()->int*` does not satisfy that.

Comment: `*fun()->int*` is a **declarator**, it's not relevant with `T`.

Comment: @jackX I suspect you have to decide if you want the `*` to be part of the return type (included in the single `auto`) or some modifier to the *declarator* (declaring a function pointer?). If you want it as part of the *declarator* then you probably need parentheses `(*func)`

Comment: @Galik Of course that `*` is as the part of declarator of a declaration. As I said in the comment below the question, `*` is not a syntax in the grammar tree of any `decl-specifier`.